# We are on the brink of getting answers to the following closed questions:

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

The idea/origins of this question is from the comments on this [answer](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/323/6687):

How it differs from that answer is that the answer linked maintains questions which are still "alive" and are closed to getting answered. This question is to keep a list of questions that are closed but were in the proximity of getting answered.

The following questions presented as an answer to this question have been closed after a significant discussion in the comments.

Some progress has been made as a result of the comments. People have provided possible solutions in some cases and/or people have encouraged some of the commenters to turn their comments into answers.

The list of questions are presented in Community Wiki format so that users can edit it if they find more such questions, or they can strike items off the list if the question does become answered.

In such cases, one thing you can do to help is to further encourage people to write answers, or even write an answer yourself if you think you can, after so much progress was made in the comment chain (which might help you to write an answer).

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to add to this list, it's a Community Wiki! Please add questions to the bottom of this list, and give each question a permanent numerical identifier so that we never have to do any re-numbering when a question does manage to graduate from this list:

- (1) [How to fix gauge in Quantum ESPRESSO?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4365/5)
- (2) [How to calculate the surface area of a stepped surface slab in a unit cell?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8680/5)
- (3) [Changing global cartesian coordinate system with VESTA](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8725/5)
- (4) [Validity of estimating electron relaxation time using the smallest cross section of a structure](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8444/5)
- (5) [Evaluating Coulomb and exchange integrals in practice using cartesian coordinates](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8591/5) (might be possible to get an answer by JJGoings).
- (6) [Transition dipole moment derivative TURBOMOLE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8595/5) (might be possible to get answered by asking someone from TURBOMOLE)
- (7) [How to gain an understanding of Material Science topics?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9290/5) (Nike can probably answer it)